# Using the showUser() in twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have the following code. It should return the user details. It works when I pass in one name("Justin") as follows.

```
 User user = twitter.showUser("Justin");
```

It does not work when I pass two words("Justin Daniel"):

```
 User user = twitter.showUser("Justin Daniel");
```

Is there a way i can represent the space and pass this string? What should I do?

Comment: showUser method accepts screenName as parameter, so searching trough the name and surname as you do won't work, you need to learn the screenName of "Justin Daniel" (or userId) to retrieve that user.

Comment: @cubbuk I need to get the screen name given the username. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check out searchUser method of twitter4j:  http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#searchUsers(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: @cubbuk Thanks. That's what I have been looking for